# Arranging funeral arrangement while being alive

Tags: hadith, death

Is is obligatory for a muslim to arrange for his/her funeral matters in his life e.g. some people start a pot or a company who take money and in case of their death if they standard money is short, the other member give money to make it as smooth as possible.

In Islam, what is the saying about leaving/saving money for your funeral and is it Obligatory or not?

Comment: Funeral expenses (needed for shroud and grave) are to be deducted from any property which you leave behind, similar to debts. If you don't leave behind any property then it is the responsibility of your heirs who are responsible for your maintenance expenses, and if your don't have any heirs then it is the responsibility of the public treasury.

Comment: @UmH people have a body (public trust) like I mention in question, is that halal or not? I heard same for life insurance but it is not halal.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, it is recommended for a Muslim to arrange for their funeral matters in advance. Although it is not obligatory, it is considered a good act of worship and a means of preparing for the inevitable journey to the hereafter.

> There are several authentic hadiths that emphasize the importance of
> preparing for one's death and funeral arrangements. One of the most
> well-known hadiths is narrated by Abdullah ibn Abbas in which the
> Prophet (peace be upon him) said,
>
> "Take advantage of five before five: your youth before your old age,
> your health before your sickness, your wealth before your poverty,
> your free time before you become occupied, and your life before your
> death." (Al-Bukhari)

This hadith suggests that one should make the most of their life and prepare for the afterlife before death. One aspect of this preparation is making arrangements for one's funeral.

> Another hadith narrated by Abu Huraira states that the Prophet (peace
> be upon him) said,
>
> "When a Muslim dies, and a group of Muslims numbering one hundred pray
> Janazah (funeral) prayer for him, all interceding for him, their
> intercession is granted." (Muslim)

This hadith shows the importance of having a proper funeral with a congregation of Muslims praying for the deceased. To ensure this, it is recommended for a Muslim to make arrangements in advance and provide for the expenses of the funeral.

> Additionally, the Prophet (peace be upon him) said,
>
> "It is better for a man to leave his heirs well-off than to leave them
> poor, begging people." (Muslim)

This hadith highlights the importance of leaving behind provisions for one's family and not burdening them with financial worries after one's death, including funeral expenses.

Therefore, while it may not be obligatory, it is highly recommended for a Muslim to arrange for their funeral matters in advance as a means of preparing for the inevitable journey to the hereafter and not burdening their family with financial worries.